# appcmd has insufficient permissions to read redirection.config

Tags: iis-7, appcmd

I have this problem with my IIS7:

```
C:\Users\vtortola.dk>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site
ERROR ( message:Configuration error
Filename: redirection.config
Line Number: 0
Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
. )
```

Every time I try to publish an ASP.NET app to my computer, I cannot use it because IIS cannot read the configuration file, and I don't know how to fix this problem.

I've found the file at `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`, and the permissions are for:

- SYSTEM
- MyDomain/Me
- Administrators (MyPC\Administrators)
- TrustedInstaller

Is this correct? What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to make sure that you run AppCmd.exe from an elevated command prompt, since otherwise you will not be running as Administrator.