# IIS 7.5, on Windows 7, IIS User can't log in, "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5, login

I am "experimenting" with Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5, on a Windows 7 OS, as an FTP site.

I have created a FTP-site, called "Opta-site", and, enabled "Anonymous Authentication", "Basic Authentication", "IisManagerAuth" and "AspNetAuth".

FTP User Isolation is not enabled (i.e., all users go straight to ftproot).

I have then tried connecting anonymously, and, it works.

Then, I created one IIS user (User name: "Opta", Password "ThePassword"), using, what I believe is, the Microsoft .Net API(?), using the following commands, in Power Shell

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Management")  

[Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthentication]::CreateUser("Opta", "ThePassword") 

[Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthorization]::Grant("Opta", "Opta-site", $FALSE)
```

And, back in the IIS Manager UI, enabled an "Allow Rule", for User "Opta", to have read and write permissions at the ftp root.

Now, when I connect, using, e.g., filezilla, or, windows ftp, I get:

```
Status: Connecting to 192.168.178.20:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER Opta
Response:   331 Password required for Opta.
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   530-User cannot log in.
Response:    Win32 error:   Access is denied. 
Response:    Error details: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
Response:    Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
Response:    
Response:    
Response:   530 End
Error:     Critical error
Error:     Could not connect to server
```

Is this a windows issue (i.e., set windows permissions, on that file "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config")? Or, something else?

I have seen other people have this/similar issue, e.g, [Serverfault question A](https://serverfault.com/questions/195308/iis7-cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions), [Serverfault question B](https://serverfault.com/questions/410470/iis-7-file-permissions-error), [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions), the last of which suggests to give "IIS_IUSRS" permissions on the file, but none of these "solutions" have worked, in this case. The issue remains, unchanged.

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the account you're attempting to connect with have permissions to/defined in the FTP root/necessary folders?

Comment: Well, in the IIS Manager UI, I have clicked the node "Opta-site" (the ftp-site), and, under FTP Authorization Rules, added an Allow Rule, for User Opta to have read/write access. So, from the IIS side, that should be ok? In Windows, the ftproot folder has permissions set for both IUSR, and IIS_IUSRS, allthoug, I'm not positive, on whether that is actually necessary...

Comment: Have you tried these configurations directions yet?  http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-ftp-7-on-iis-7

Comment: Aha! This: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7 Specifically, these permissions: `ICACLS "%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" /Grant "Network Service":R /T
ICACLS "%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config" /Grant "Network Service":R
ICACLS "%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config" /Grant "Network Service":R`  worked! Awesome, for pointing in that direction, TechieJoe! Thanks! Appreciate it!! Happy :)