# How to enable access to redirection.config

Tags: security, iis, ftp

I'm using windows server 2012 R2 as an FTP server. I added an FTP site MyFtpServer. The application pool it uses is MyFtpServerAppPool. The AppPool uses ApplicationPoolIdentity as identity. If I use ftp from the commandline to log in, I get the following result:

```
530-User cannot log in.
 Win32 error:   Access is denied.
 Error details: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config
 Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
```

When I add permission to \windows\system32\inetsrv\config folder by adding Network Services identity with read access.... then the FTP login proceeds without error.

But what I read about using Network Services like this, is that security wise, this would be 2 steps back. The 'best practice' solution I found was to add permissions using the IIS AppPool\MyFtpServerAppPool identity. However if I do that, then the FTP login fails again with same error message.

So my question is, what would be best way to solve this issue? Obviously, I want the FTP functionality to work, but I don't want to revert back to measures which are no longer considered best practice security wise.
Any ideas?

Added: I'm using IIS Manager Users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS FTP server by defaults runs under `Network Service`, I think changing the Application pool identity is not helpful, because the FTP services doesn't even use the application pools or the `w3wp.exe` processes.

Some people recommend to use a specific account to run the FTP service and then assign permissions to that account.

You do that in the `Component Services` mmc, see a [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2011/12/01/changing-the-identity-of-the-ftp-7-extensibility-process/), I tried that but I didn't even see the `FTP...` node under `COM+ Applications`

It took a while to find out that I have to install the `FTP Extensibility` Windows feature in Server Manager.

After that you should see the `Microsoft FTP Publishing Service Extensibility Host` node. Open properties and change the Identity to a custom account.

I just wrote a PowerShell script that enables FTP, creates a site and a user and sets the identity for the FTP service. Set ACLs for the new account on the configuration files and the ftp root.

[New-DemoFTPSite.ps1](https://github.com/hahndorf/hacops/blob/master/New-DemoFtpSite.ps1)

Comment: ha, it doesnt even us Application pool ... indeed I see a FTP service running. Makes sense (whish I knew before, could have saved me hours...)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer of changing the account of the FTP service. And for the ps1 .. really nice.